# Development of android application in TEAM

Tags: android, development-environment

In my company we have started development in android application.
Our problem is there are multiple developers for same application and usually need to work on same files so it is really difficult to integrate  work each one of us does. Also we are looking for versioning system also .

For php development we used VSS where on one file only developer can work which was fine but unable to use it for android since we moved to ubuntu and everyone is having their own eclipse setup.
Please suggest solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search on _Google_ before asked.

Comment: Use SVN it will solve your problem

Answer (score 5):

So you are looking for a versionning control system. I recommend to use [GIT](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git), you can host the remote on [github](https://github.com/) (as it's free for public repository), on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) (for 5 users private repository) or on your own server with GitLab

Comment: I agree with this. Git is very good with merging multiple changes to the same file. It sounds like your developers are also used to having long locks on each individual file they are working on. This is now commonly considered an anti-pattern. Instead, make a small change, test it, push it upstream. Constantly be pulling and pushing from upstream. This will reduce the overall time spent merging files. Also consider breaking up important functionality into multiple files so that they can be merged without incidentally making other's merges more difficult.